# How can I get the ID of the div that a draggable object which was just dropped on this USED to be dropped into?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I need something likt this:

```
$('#dropZOne').droppable({
  drop: function(ui,event) 
        {
          $($(ui).getPreviousDropZone()).droppable('options',{disabled:false});
        }
});
```

I hope my fake method is illustrative enough of what I need!

Comment: not sure if this will work in your case but you can store that id on the dragged item when the page loads `data-previous-drop-id="x"` then `ui.draggable.data('previous-drop-id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you record the location it came from when the drag starts, or when the page loads? It's hard to tell with whats provided, but that would be my suggestion.

IE - Page loads... store the droppable item the item is in (if it is in one) 
On every drop, retrieve the "from" information, then record the new from location for the next drag, if thats the way you want it to work.

Comment: I believe I can fire a start: callback.  Thanks!  If that works you got the green check

Answer (score 1):

buddy, seems you use the jquery drag and drop plugin, if you want to get the id of drag then you can use the parameter: ui, just almost like your fake code. if you want to get the id of drop, definitely you can use $(this) in you code. it is the drop element.

Comment: No I need to re-enable it on whichever node that element was drug out of.